# Reading a big .tar.gz file in ruby line by line

Tags: ruby, zlib

I have a big zipped file (in GBs) with extension .tar.gz, which contains huge sql queries in each line so I want to read it line by line. Currently I am using TarReader and Zlib gem to do it below way:

```
tar_extract = Gem::Package::TarReader.new(Zlib::GzipReader.open('/Users/sachin.japate/Desktop/80637.tar.gz'))
tar_extract.rewind
tar_extract.each do |entry|
    if entry.file?
        query_list = entry.read.split("\n")
        puts query_list
    end
end
```

now the issue here is: when the file is very big this is going out of integer range, and giving this error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby-flo/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader/entry.rb:126:in `read': integer 7422013772 too big to convert to `int' (RangeError)
```

then I tried it this way:

```
query = ""
while byte = entry.getc do
   query = query + byte
   if byte == "\n"
      puts query
      query = ""
   end
end
```

Although this is working but this is very slow and impacting the performance, so my question is: Is there any way to read big TarReader entry object line by line in memory efficiently?

Comment: _"going out of integer range"_ – what do you mean by that?

Comment: Doing it character by character, *especially* when composing using `q=q+b`, is going to be murderously slow. Try calling `GC.start` after each file's processed to see if that can free up any garbage.

Comment: @Stefan: updated the question with range error